# Parsing timestamp in Google Sheets with script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a spreadsheet with a form that timestamps every time the form is submitted. I'm writing a script to change the background color of the timestamped cell if it is more than seven minutes after a certain time.

Is there a way to compare time without comparing date in the API?

Should I convert the timestamp to another format (a string or something) to compare it?

<sub>I need to highlight the cell if it's after 6:07pm on any given day.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code will set the background color of the entire row:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // get data and make it a 1D array
  var time = e.range.getValues()[0];

  // get the minutes and hours of the timestamp (time[0]) 
  var minutes = time[0].getMinutes(), hours = time[0].getHours();

  // calculate the total amount of minutes
  var totalMin = (hours * 60) + minutes;

  // do the logic (thanks to geekzspot for the 1087)
  if(totalMin > 1087) {
    e.range.setBackgroundColor('yellow');
  } else {
    e.range.setBackgroundColor('red'); 
  }  
}
```

**UPDATE**
This code will set only the back ground color of the timestamp:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // get active spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get data and make it a 1D array
  var time = e.range.getValues()[0];

  // get row index
  var row = e.range.getRowIndex();

  // get the minutes and hours  
  var minutes = time[0].getMinutes(), hours = time[0].getHours();

  // calculate the total amount of minutes
  var totalMin = (hours * 60) + minutes;

  // set range to timestamp
  var range = sh.setActiveCell("A"+row);

  // do the logic (thanks to geekzspot for the 1087)
  if(totalMin > 1087) {
    range.setBackgroundColor('yellow');
  } else {
    range.setBackgroundColor('red'); 
  }  
}
```

Add this script, via the script editor, to your spreadsheet and set the trigger:
[image]

Here's the form: [Test For Web Applications](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDljQkdzVlM1SFdaNEQ1ZzY0YmhNTmc6MQ#gid=0) and here's the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDljQkdzVlM1SFdaNEQ1ZzY0YmhNTmc#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks. This was so long ago I hardly remember working on it, but I marked your code as the answer. Better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an exact solution form you, but..

You could use a cell formula like this `=IF(HOUR(A2)*60+MINUTE(A2) > 1087,"Late","On time")`, then right-click on the cell and use Conditional formatting... to color the cells.

- A2 in the formula is the cell where the timestamp is
- 1087 is the value for 18:07 (6:07 pm in 24 hour time) that you get
  from the above formula of hour * 60 (to give minutes) + minutes.

Comment: I'll try that. I'm kind of considering the script though since in the long run it will allow us to add more fuctionality.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be with Conditional formatting (which need not preclude applying GAS for other purposes). Assuming the time stamps are Date/Time in Number format (Text would require some adaptation to the formula below) and that these are in ColumnA, select ColumnA and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=mod(A1,1)>0.7542
```

with formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

[MOD](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)

`.7542` is an approximation for 6:07 PM, but well within one second.